# Mapping Dates to Numbers in Time Series using PHP

Tags: php, time-series

I'm working on an algorithm that analyzes time series, and I'd like to know if it's safe to give values of `[0,1,2,...,n-1,n]` to date if the dates are evenly spaced:

For example:

Is it safe to map dates to values this way?

```
2013-07-01 => 0
2013-07-08 => 1
2013-07-15 => 2
2013-07-22 => 3
2013-07-29 => 4
```

For example, If I'm keeping track of sales per week my database looks like:

```
+------------+---------+
|     Date   |  Sales  |
+------------+---------+
| 2013-07-01 |   24    |
+------------+---------+
| 2013-07-08 |   12    |
+------------+---------+
| 2013-07-15 |   25    |
+------------+---------+
| 2013-07-22 |   10    |
+------------+---------+
| 2013-07-29 |   29    |
+------------+---------+
```

That would be equivalent to:

```
P(x,y) = { (0, 24), (1, 12), (2, 25), (3, 10), (4, 29) }
```

This way I will be able to use the formula:

```
Y2 - Y1
-------
X2 - X1
```

or in PHP (my application's language):

```
function isSeriesIncreasing($points) {
    $x1 = current($points);
    $y1 = key($points);
    $x2 = end($points);
    $y2 = key($points);
    return (($y2 - $y1)/($x2 - $x1) > 0) ? true: false;
}

$timeSeries = array(24,12,25,10,29);

if( isSeriesIncreasing($timeSeries) ) {
    echo "Sales have been increasing";
} else {
   echo "Sales have been decreasing";
}
```

So my question is:

Is it good idea to map dates to numbers in time series? 
Is there a better way to do this in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that.  You lose and distance information between the dates when you do that.  It would probably be better to set your first x value to 0, and the latter the change in dates.

Comment: Could you rephrase your comment, I'm afraid that I don't quite understand what you were trying to say. I'm setting the value of x1 to 0.

Comment: Well each of your dates are 7 days apart, so what you are doing is perfectly valid.  If you are planning have days that are a variable length apart, you can set x1 to 0, and set the latter dates x values to the number of days they are apart.